# Not able to grep telnet output correctly

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, telnet

I am writing an script to verify connectivity for multiple external system with timeout of 10s.
How do i avoid "Connection closed by foreign host" text from this script. I am doing grep only for escape text but for some reason "Connection closed by foreign host" this is also getting output

```
   [MASKED@MASKED scripts]$ ./test1.sh
    Bloomerberg1 Failed
    Connection closed by foreign host.
    Scorecardgrid Successful
    Sewa Failed
    
    This is coming for all Successful connectivity. 
    
    #!/bin/bash
    RED='\033[0;31m'
    NC='\033[0m' # No Color
    
    echo quit | timeout --signal=9 10 telnet   HOSTNAMEMASKED PORTMASKED | grep -i escape 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
    
    if [ "$?" == "0" ]
    then
       echo "Bloomerberg1 Successful"
    else
       echo -e "${RED}Bloomerberg1 Failed${NC}"
    fi
    
    echo quit | timeout --signal=9 10 telnet  HOSTNAMEMASKED PORTMASKED | grep -i escape 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
    
    if [ "$?" == "0" ]
    then
       echo "Scorecardgrid Successful"
    else
       echo -e "${RED}Scorecardgrid Failed${NC}"
    fi
    
    echo quit | timeout --signal=9 10 telnet  HOSTNAMEMASKED PORTMASKED  | grep -i escape 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
    
    
    if [ "$?" == "0" ]
    then
       echo "Sewa Successful"
    else
       echo -e "${RED}Sewa Failed${NC}"
    fi
```

Comment: That message is output by telnet on its stderr, which you did not redirect so it goes to the terminal. (OTOH your grep doesn't need stderr redirected, and you don't need to redirect stdout if you use `-q`.)

Comment: What is your definition of "connectivity"  A TCP connection?  A login prompt?  Would a ping response suffice?

Comment: @MarcWilson - A TCP connection to verify network connectivity is open between source and destination on that port. No ping won't suffice here.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 There is no -q option in telnet in our OS Usage: telnet [-4] [-6] [-8] [-E] [-L] [-S tos] [-a] [-c] [-d] [-e char] [-l user]
        [-n tracefile] [-b hostalias ] [-r]

Comment: shell is the wrong language for this.  Use tcl's [expect](https://core.tcl.tk/expect/), perl's [Expect.pm](https://metacpan.org/release/AUSCHUTZ/Expect.pm-1.07) or [Net::Telnet](https://metacpan.org/release/Net-Telnet), or python's [pexpect](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect).   or if you just want to do a one-shot data grab and don't need to maintain an interactive connection, use something like [netcat](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/nc/)

Comment: The output **from grep** can be suppressed by the **`-q` option OF GREP**.  My entire parenthetical second sentence was about grep, in contrast to the first sentence about telnet.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Same issue with -q

Comment: [MASKED@MASKED script]$ echo quit | timeout --signal=9 10 telnet  MASKED 443 | grep -q Escape 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
Connection closed by foreign host.
[MASKED@MASKED script]$

Comment: @cas nc didn't helped us as it was giving error even though connectivity is open [MASKED@MASKED script]$ echo 'QUIT' | nc -w MASKED 443
Ncat: Connection reset by peer.

Comment: As I said (in my **first sentence** because it is more important) 'connection closed by foreign host' is coming from telnet on stderr, and you need to **redirect stderr FROM telnet** (NOT from grep) to fix that. Using `-q` on grep avoids the need to redirect stdout from grep; that is a completely separate and independent concept. For people who don't think: `echo quit | timeout --signal=9 10 telnet $host $port 2>/dev/null | grep -q Escape`.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks i got the point now and it is working. appreciate that.