# netcat command not working

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, netcat

Any idea why nc command is not working and telnet is working.
Ideally nc will also work. I am trying to use nc in script but getting error however telnet is working. Ideally nc command is working for all internal connectivity and for external connectivity giving below error.

```
[MASKED@MASKED script]$ echo 'QUIT' | nc -w 10 DESTHOSTNAME1 443
Ncat: Connection reset by peer.
[MASKED@MASKED script]$

[MASKED@MASKED script]$ telnet DESTHOSTNAME1 443
Trying DESTHOSTNAME1...
Connected to DESTHOSTNAME1.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet> quit
```

Comment: Is this GNU netcat or BSD netcat? Does the connection reset happen immediately, or after the 10 seconds? Does the connection reset happen even if you don't send anything, the same way you use telnet?

Comment: I assume this is a follow-up to [Not able to grep telnet output correctly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/705745/100397)? Not a problem if so; simply referencing one from the other in case the context is helpful

Comment: Of course the comparison done isn't comparable. Try instead `echo QUIT | telnet  DESTHOSTNAME1 443` to get telnet get a `Connection closed by foreign host.`: in both cases QUIT is sent to the remote service, not to the command. You're using telnet or netcat as a probing tool for a remote service, but what matters is what is the remote service. For example port 443 suggests TLS/SSL. Then using a ssl enabled command such as... `telnet-ssl -z ssl ...` or `socat openssl:...` would be advised. What matters is the remote service but the question gives no clue about it. Check https://xyproblem.info/